# inject a require into a js vendor module

Tags: javascript, webpack

About the framework (while I think the problem itself does not heavily rely on that): Angular 2 with Webpack

There is the library [Leaflet.heat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.heat) which relies on [simpleheat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpleheat). I got the missing type definitions under control.
I'm importing the libraries in my `vendor.ts`

```js
[...]
import 'simpleheat';
import 'leaflet.heat/src/HeatLayer';
[...]
```

Inside of the [HeatLayer class](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/blob/gh-pages/src/HeatLayer.js), the function simpleheat:

```js
[simpleheat.js]
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') module.exports = simpleheat;

function simpleheat(canvas) {
...
```

is called. However, the HeatLayer module file does not require simpleheat inside it's file.
Thus, creating an instance of `L.HeatLayer` works, but the execution of the respective code in it's function fails with

```js
ReferenceError: simpleheat is not defined
```

Now, adding (for testing purposes) `simpleheat = require('simpleheat');` into the HeatLayer file (a vendor), it works.
Understandably, I don't want to modify a vendor file.

**Question:**
What options do I have, to make the function `simpleheat` accessible from inside the HeatLayer module?

Answer (score 0):

One Solution I just found:

Change the `vendor.ts` to the following:

```js
(<any>window).simpleheat = require('simpleheat');
import 'leaflet.heat/src/HeatLayer';
```

Are there others/better?